# show magento scope switcher in admin grid edit form

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a module in magento admin where I would like to show the `scope selector` as in manage products, manage categories, system configuration for my grid edit form.

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone help me how could I add that and `store values in database specific to the scope selected`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By searching on the store switcher, you can see Magento adds it by adding it in the layout file:

```
<your_layout_handle_here>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" template="store/switcher.phtml" />
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle_here>
```

Comment: and how will I get the value of currently selected scope to be saved in my table?

Comment: also, If I do change the scope it shows me an alert message. but in case of magento's default modules it do not show any alert

Answer (score 0):

For not show the confirm alert add an action in this block as in a core

```
 <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" before="-">
      <action method="setUseConfirm"><params>0</params></action>
 </block>
```